# Como fazer um break do retorno de um processo de PID em TXT?

Tags: linux, shell-script, break

tenho um processamento, que gera um PID (exemplo 12345).
Para saber o andamento desse processo, fiz um LOG que traz o resultado do PID 12345 a cada 60seg e faz um output em arquivo TXT.

`nohup echo "Checking run time"`
`while true`
`do sleep 60`
`ps -p 12345-o pid,cmd,lstart,etime,etimes`
`done >> LOG.txt &`

Esse LOG, ficou infinito, pois quando o processo 12345 acaba, continua capturando o resultado vazio.

Como efetuar um break, para que ao retornar o resultado vazio do PID 12345, o LOG finalize ?

Tipo isso:

`v_PID=$(ps -ef 12345)`

`if [[ "" !=  "$v_PID" ]]; then`
`echo "killing $PID"`
`kill $v_PID`
`fi`

Obrigado por toda e qualquer ajuda !!!

Answer (score 0):

Olá.
Voce pode trocar o direcionador ">>" pelo tee.

Seguindo o exemplo:

```
    #!/bin/bash
clear
pteste=/files/cpd/shell/pteste/

cd $pteste
    if [ -e "log_pid" ];
        then
            rm log_pid
                touch log_pid
                    chmod 777 log_pid
            sleep 1
        else
            touch log_pid
                chmod 777 log_pid
            sleep 1
        fi
    sleep 1
ps -ef | grep nfs | cut -c 10-15 | tee -a $pteste/log_pid
cat log_pid
```

Onde ele ira buscar o pid com o cut -c coluna-coluna e direcionar para o log_pid.
Apos voce utiliza o grep em conjunto com o cut para redirecionar novamente o pid correto, pois as vezes o ps busca mais de um pid na pesquisa.

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Obrigado Igor Ferreira pela sua resposta. Preciso testar e retorno com um parecer.